# Split a perl string with a substring and a space

Tags: perl

```
local_addr = sjcapp [value2]
```

How do you split this string so that I get 2 values in my array i.e. 
`array[0] = sjcapp` and `array[1] = value2`.

If I do this

```
@array = split('local_addr =', $input)
```

then my `array[0]` has `sjcapp [value2]`. I want to be able to separate it into two in my `split` function itself.

I was trying something like this but it didn't work:

```
split(/local_addr= \s/, $input)
```

Answer (score 2):

Untested, but maybe something like this?

```
@array = ($input =~ /local_addr = (\S+)\s\[(\S+)\]/);
```

Rather than `split`, this uses a regex match in list context, which gives you an array of the parts captured in parentheses.

Comment: Since the file has a consistent structure wouldn't using ```split``` be faster and simpler than a regexp for large datasets?  I used ```awk``` style perl "autosplit" in my response below, but ```sed``` or ```cut``` could do this too. Of course perl has the advantage of being portable :-)

Comment: I assumed this was within a Perl script, rather than using Perl as a command-line processor, but I see now it could be either. I also assumed the `[` and `]` were literal and needed to be discarded, which makes a regex necessary at some point. I doubt performance is going to be an issue unless the file is humongous, so a case of TMTOWTDI, I guess :)

Answer (score 1):

```
~/ cat data.txt    
  local_addr = sjcapp [value2]
  other_addr = superman [value1492]
  euro_addr = overseas [value0]
```

If the data really is as regularly structured as that , then you can just split on the whitespace. On the command line (see the `perlrun(1)` manual page) this is easiest with "autosplit" (`-a`) which  magically creates an array of fields called `@F` from the input:

```
perl -lane 'print "$F[2] $F[3]" ' data.txt
sjcapp [value2]
superman [value1492]
overseas [value0]
```

In your script you can change the name of array, and the position of the elements within,it by `shift`-ing or `splice`-ing - possibly in a more elegant way than this - but it works:

```
perl -lane 'my @array = ($F[2],$F[3]) ; print "$array[0], $array[1]" ' data.txt
```

Or, without using autosplit, as follows :

```
perl -lne 'my @arr=split(" ");splice(@arr,0,2); print "$arr[0] $arr[1]"' data.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

## try :

```
if ( $input =~ /(=)(.+)(\[)(.+)(\])/ ) { 
   @array=($2,$4);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a regexp rather than a split, since this is clearly a standard format config file line.  How you construct your regexp will likely depend on the full line syntax and how  flexible you want to be.

```
if( $input =~ /(\S+)\s*=\s*(\S+)\s*\[\s*(\S+)\s*\]/ ) {
    @array = ($2,$3);
}
```